# Probability for Multiples using only mean and SD

Tags: probability

An orange juice producer sources his oranges from a large grove. The amount of juice extracted from a single orange is normally distributed with mean 141 ml and standard deviation 12 ml.

Describe the probability distribution of the total amount of juice from a sample of 20 oranges? What is the probability that this total is less than 2750ml?

Lost on both the answer and how to describe....Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this problem? What have you tried, and where are you having difficulty? This will help people write an appropriate answer the addresses your problem. Questions that include this information tend to have a much better response.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What do you know about sums of random variables with normal distributions?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, how much juice each orange produces independent of each other. I am assuming you are in a very basic/low level/intro stats class.

If I call $x$ the sum of juice each orange produces, then it turns out (it is a fact) that 
$$\text{avg }x = \text{population avg.}$$
In this case $\text{avg }x = 141\text{ ml}$.

It turns (it is a fact) that, since each amount of juice is independent of another, then variance of $x$ is
$$\text{var } x = n\times \text{pop. var.}$$
Thus, the standard deviation
$$\text{sd } x = \sqrt{n\times\text{pop. var}} = \sqrt{n}\times\text{ pop. sd.}$$

> Describe the probability distribution of the total amount of juice from a sample of 20 oranges? What is the probability that this total is less than 2750ml?

1. (Describe) If $x$ is the sum of juice from the 20 oranges, then it's asking for the average and variance (sd) of $x$.
2. (Probability) It's asking for the probability that $x< 270\text{ ml}$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to view your sample of $20$ oranges as $20$ **independent** random variables with the normal distribution with the particular expected value and standard deviation that you give.  Have you heard that the expected value and variance of the sum of independent random variables (regardless of whether they're normally distributed are not) is just the sum of the separate expected values and variances?  That would tell you to look at
$$
\underbrace{141\text{ ml} + \cdots + 141\text{ ml}}_\text{$20$ terms}
$$
and
$$
\underbrace{(12\text{ ml})^2 + \cdots + (12\text{ ml})^2}_\text{$20$ terms}.
$$
The one other thing you need is that the sum of independent normally distributed random variables is normally distributed.

The gives you the distribution of the total amount of juice from the $20$ oranges.